# Problem with removing a file from a PR using git rm

Tags: git

I merged in a PR to my local branch while that PR was yet to be merged into remote dev. While I was still working on the branch locally that PR got merged into dev. Fast forward, I raised a PR, there were merged conflicts in the files of that other PR and some of my own files, I fixed my own files but I decided to delete the files introduced by that merge using git rm because they are actually not needed in my PR
Question, will this cause those files to be deleted from remote dev when my PR gets merged?

Comment: Yes, the changes shown in the PR (including deletions) will be applied to the branch the PR is being merged to.

Comment: Why did you merge the PR when you don't need it? Maybe you can create a clean branch based off current master where you cherry-pick all your individual commits.